# How to clear the text field automatically

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift2, uitextfield

I have a question about `UITextField()` in Swift. How can I clear the text in the text field when I click on it?

My `textField.text = "0"`. I want to automatically remove the number "0" when I click on the text field:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var lbltext: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var scrolview1: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var fi: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var scrolviewus: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var counterLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fi.text = "0"
       }

       override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
       }

       @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        lbltext.numberOfLines = 0
        lbltext.text! = lbltext.text! + "\n" + fi.text! + "\n" + "---  "
    }
 }
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530167/objective-c-auto-erase-nstextfield-string

Comment: So what, it's the same concept.

Comment: i am first time using swift
 and i don't know how to objective-c

Comment: Well, if you read the other question there is no answer, (obj-c and swift apis are similar in some ways) so it might be just that. If there is a way then hopefully someone will explain... good luck :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use this method,

If you want to manually clear the text field use this code:

```
textField.text = ""
```

If you want the text field to empty when you begin editing, use the delegate method below:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.text = ""
}
```

If you are using multiple text fields, use the method below:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) { 
    if (textField == oneTextField) {
       textField.text = ""
    } 
    else if (textField == anotherTextField) {
       // Perform any other operation
    } 
}
```

Comment: What if I have two textfiled, 1 , 2 , 
and when I click on the first 1textfiled will remove "0", 
and then when i click on second textfiled2 will remove "0", 
I want to return the value of the first textfiled when i click on textfiled2 or anywhere

Comment: you want differentiate the textfield, check the condition below format,  `   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == fi {
            
        } else if textField == anotherTextFieldName {
            
        }
    }' check the condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111271/discussion-between-iyyappan-ravi-and-x-bozo).

Comment: its check your textfield is equal to yourTextFieldName then call the particular textfield only this code is comment for you

Comment: if textField == TextFailde.text { here what i write ?}

Comment: write what you want `fi.text = ""` or you give any function in particular textfield, mainly  particular textfield only call the action

Comment: its small issue set the break point and check, ok Thank you bro

Comment: i use this function (func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField))

Answer (score 10):

You can easily clear the TextField in swift

```
emailTextField.text?.removeAll()
passwordTextField.text?.removeAll()
confirmPasswordTextField.text?.removeAll()
```

Comment: I am surprised that there are so many answers quoting "" instead of this one. There is literally a function to accomplish this.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method to handle focus change, and clear text.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.text = ""
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    if fi.text == "0"
    {
        fi.text = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can solve this problem, depending on what you're looking for. The first is to use a placeholder instead of setting the text to 0. A placeholder will disappear whenever the user starts typing and reappear if they type nothing in:

```
fi.placeholder = "0"
```

if you want the 0 to be the value and not just a placeholder, there are lots of built in methods to track editing/entering/returning/etc of a textfield. This does require implementation of the UITextFieldDelegate however, which it appears you have already done.

```
var isFirstTime = true

override viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     fi.delegate = self
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    isFirstTime = false
    if fi.text == "0" {
        fi.text = ""
    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if fi.text.isEmpty {
        fi.text = "0"
        isFirstTime = true
    }
}
```

The is first time var is only present so that the user can type 0 if they choose. If the user should not be able to type 0, then it may be removed.

Comment: thank you so much , your code doesn't work with me i think we should use func textFieldDidBeginEditing

Comment: Whoops, misread the question that'll be correct. Essentially the same thing. Be careful with the other answers though as they are largely incomplete; if you always set the text to "" on begin editing than anytime the user enters the field whatever they have typed will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        fi.text = ""
    }

func textFieldDidEndEdition(textField: UITextField) {

     if fi.text isEqualToString:@"" {
          fi.text = @""
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use `clearsOnBeginEditing` property of textfield.

```
textfield.clearsOnBeginEditing = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a small button on the right corner of textfield. Create action of that button.

```
@IBAction func removeSearchTFTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    searchTF.text = ""
}
```